# jQuery UI Datepicker weird behavior shows weird icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i have a weird behavior with date picker , and not reprduce for all computers, 
the problem after select date from start date and then try to select from the end date , for some computers there additional arrow icons that appear in the date picker.
picture attached.

now the problem didn't reprduce for all , also it reprduce when get the minDate or maxDate related if you in start or end date

i've tested the issue on two computers that have a same os and browser versions but it reproduced on one of them

```
var from = $(".from", container).datepicker({
                        defaultDate: defaultDate,
                        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 3,
                        showOn: "both",
                        buttonImage: "/resources/images/forms/calendar-regular.png",
                        buttonText: "Start Date",
                        minDate : minDate,
                        maxDate: -1,
                        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                            $(".to", container).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                            if (!$(".to", container).val()) {
                                $(".to", container).datepicker('setDate', selectedDate);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    var to = $(".to", container).datepicker({
                        defaultDate: defaultDate,
                        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 3,
                        showOn: "both",
                        buttonImage: "/resources/images/forms/calendar-regular.png",
                        buttonText: "End Date",
                        minDate: minDate,
                        maxDate: 0,
                        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                            $(".from", container).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                        }
                    });
                },
```

i'm using jquery-ui-1.9.1.js

[image]

Comment: Make sure the jQuery UI CSS file is for the same version as the Javascript.

Comment: Since this can't be reproduced on all computers, what browsers / OS is this issue confirmed to occur on?

Comment: @TidyDev i checked with comupter that exactly have the same os and the same chrome version .